# Angular Cli Webpack Barrel Files Not Resolving

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I just switched my Angular 2 project over from SystemJS to Webpack and am now using angular-cli@webpack.

After repairing a few small things here and there, the biggest sticking point seems that my barrel files are no longer being resolved as expected.

ie. I've been doing my imports like:

```
import { ServiceA, ServiceB, ModelZ } from '../shared/index'
```

At compile time, they seem to be resolved.  tslint doesn't complain and neither does Typescript when I compile.

At runtime however, they're all resolved to `undefined`.

To fix this issue, I can change them to:

```
import { ServiceA } from './shared/services/service-a.service
import { ServiceB } from './shared/services/service-b.service
import { ModelZ } from './shared/models/ModelZ
```

Having pointed the imports to their specific files, they can be resolved at runtime and everything works without a hitch.  But I don't want to have to do that.  I like barrel files!

Notes: This switch required an upgrade to Typescript 2.0.0.  So that's the other big new thing here.  But I'm assuming the issue is with the way Webpack is bundling these together.  I'm not super familiar with Webpack.

Comment: One odd thing that fixed this problem for me was reordering the imports in the barrel files. Not sure if this is true or not, but the conclusion I came up with, based on the reordering, is that the model import would have to go before the service import because the model is used by the service. Again this is just the conclusion I came up with. I dont know if it's true or not, but it fixed the problem fo me. This is maybe  a [related issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1831)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1585 --> An issue was filed back in September. Since the CLI doesn't expose the webpack config, it looks like we're out of luck using barrels.

Comment: Yes, I've stopped using them entirely for anything that is being injected.  They still work for my models (just plain old Typescript objects) but that's all.